# Sysctl IPv6 disable autoconfig for all interfaces not working

Tags: networking, server, ipv6

I am trying to turn off IPv6 autoconfig for my all interfaces (I have 4).
I want to use

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
```

In the my sysctl config (under `/etc/sysct.d`)
But the settings not applied for any interface, however for the `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf` parameter it works, so
runnig the following command: `

`sysctl -a | grep "net\.ipv6\.conf" | grep "autoconf"`

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth3.autoconf = 1
```

Then I tried with on the fly setting with

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
```

But neither its working. Do you know any workaround for this?
The reasons why I didn't want to do it by one by one (`net.ipv6.conf.eth3.autoconf = 0` manually), because sometimes I have more interfaces too (these are just not connected always)

Comment: Did you also try sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0 ?

Comment: This alos might be helpful https://superuser.com/questions/33196/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-on-ipv6-in-linux , esp. the last comment stating "The problem with Ubuntu 18 and ipv6 is that systemd-networkd controls kernel parameters, so though one might disable ipv6 with sysctl, networkd will be more than happy switching them on for you, if the configuration does not state otherwise. "

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? You really shouldn't do that.

Comment: Its a server machine, and in my infrastructure I want to do that. Moreover "You really shouldn't do that' won't solve my problem.

@alci I have tried sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0 , but its an another thing, it will modify the newly created interfaces behaviour!
Morover thanks for the link it seems to be useful!

Comment: I do not think, that wil be possible. I try your command `sysctl -a | grep "net\.ipv6\.conf" | grep "autoconf"´ in my debian. the values were read from `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/stable_secret. and secret means really secret. More explaination I found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251401/cannot-read-key-net-ipv6-conf-all-stable-secret-in-sysctl

Comment: I'm not very active here as I'm not running Ubuntu any more but I feel your pain and you're probably doing this on not one machine but a ton, so see answer below.  **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
for sInterface in /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*; do sysctl --write $(echo $sInterface.autoconf=0 | sed "s#/#.#g" | sed "s/.proc.sys.//g"); done
```

should do it.

### The long version:

- `sysctl` actually changes file contents in `/proc/sys`
- `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf` is thus physically located in `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/autoconf`
- so we iterate over `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/`
- we change all `/`  to  `.` using `sed` using the `#` separator
- we remove `.proc.sys.` from the string again using `sed` using the standard `/` separator.
- we add `.autoconf=0` to the interface
- and apply with `sysctl --write $()`

---

**Note:** If you're not running as `root` you should do a `sudo sysctl --write $()` instead...